# How do I force my angular app to check for ng-show conditions?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on a project where there is a huge part of the ui that is hidden shown based on conditions.

The problem I am having is that some conditions checks are not being executed and so the items are being displayed.

These are some examples which I know are valid ng-show parameters but are not triggering :

```
ng-show="model.staff.length == 0"

ng-show="model2.companytype == 'Contractor' && model2.program.ahu"

ng-show="model2.companytype == 'Contractor' && model2.program.hu"
```

I have time and again confirmed the values are right for the ngshow conditions to be true, or false as per what I need, but nothing happens.

So what I wanted to know, is how can I force all the ng-shows to execute? Or well all the watches in my angular app.

Comment: You can call `$scope.$apply()` to trigger a digest cycle, but as long as all of your calls are in scope this will happen automatically. Do you have a lot of AJAX requests that are outside Angulars scope?

Comment: Make sure anything you are using as a Boolean value is really a Boolean and not the string 'true' or 'false'. I just ran into that recently.

Comment: Have you tried using $watch() on the variables?
I had a similar issue before and using $watch() did the trick for me. 
This will trigger a $digest cycle each time your variables' values change. 
Here's a link to the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Let me know if you need more help!